# Trying to get multiple elements to load with random positioning

Tags: javascript, random

So I'm not super great at JS yet, but I found this code block that does exactly what I need it to do - takes an element and makes it's position random. The problem is this only works if I use `getElementById`, but I want to do this with about 12 different elements, not just the one.

Ive tried giving them all the same class and using `getElementsByClassName`, I've tried using `querySelector`, I've tried `querySelectorAll` - With each one of these examples the code either doesn't work, or it only works for the first element.

Markup:

```
<div id="1" class="rando">
     <img src="someIMG" alt="logo" itemprop="image">
</div>

<div id="2" class="rando">
    <iframe width="200" height="250" src="someURL" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function getRandomPosition(element) {
    var x = document.body.offsetHeight-element.clientHeight;
    var y = document.body.offsetWidth-element.clientWidth;
    var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random()*x);
    var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random()*y);
    return [randomX,randomY];
}

window.onload = function() {
    var rpos = document.getElementsByClassName("rando");
    rpos.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;");
    document.body.appendChild(rpos);
    var xy = getRandomPosition(rpos);
    rpos.style.top = xy[0] + 'px';
    rpos.style.left = xy[1] + 'px';
}
```

I also tried putting these through a loop, but that didn't work either:

```
function getRandomPosition(element) {
    var x = document.body.offsetHeight-element.clientHeight;
    var y = document.body.offsetWidth-element.clientWidth;
    var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random()*x);
    var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random()*y);
    return [randomX,randomY];
}

window.onload = function() {
    var rpos = document.querySelector("#1, #2");
    for (var i = 0; i &lt; rpos.length; i++) {
        rpos.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;");
        document.body.appendChild(rpos);
        var xy = getRandomPosition(rpos);
        rpos.style.top = xy[0] + 'px';
        rpos.style.left = xy[1] + 'px';
    }
}
```

Any help / direction is, as always, greatly appreciated!

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. In your for loop you operate on the entire HTMLCollection `rpos` rather than each seperate element. For example what this line `rpos.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;");` does is *run setAttribute for this collection of elements*, rather than *for each element in this collection we should run setAttribute*. With a small adjustment you get this:

```js
function getRandomPosition(element) {
  var x = document.body.offsetHeight - element.clientHeight;
  var y = document.body.offsetWidth - element.clientWidth;
  var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * x);
  var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * y);
  return [randomX, randomY];
}

window.onload = function() {
  const rpos = document.getElementsByClassName("rando");
  for (let rpo of rpos) {
    rpo.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;");
    document.body.appendChild(rpo);
    var xy = getRandomPosition(rpo);
    rpo.style.top = xy[0] + "px";
    rpo.style.left = xy[1] + "px";
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="1" class="rando">
     <img src="someIMG" alt="logo" itemprop="image">
</div>

<div id="2" class="rando">
    <iframe width="200" height="250" src="someURL" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
</div>

<p class="rando">Test A</p>
<p class="rando">Test B</p>
<p class="rando">Test C</p>
```

Comment: Okay, this makes sense to me. Thanks for the demo!

Comment: Great  Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, your `getElementsByClassName` returns an Array-like collection. Your `rpos` variable therefore contains something you need to loop over. Loop over `rpos` and it should work.

Alternatively, in your second example, `querySelector` only returns the first element corresponding to that selector, so not something you can loop over. Change this to `querySelectorAll` to get an iterable list.

EDIT: I just noticed your `for` loop as it stands won't work either. Don't forget that you need to manipulate each element in the list, not the list as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop in the second example, you need to work on each individual item, something like:

````
window.onload = function() {
    var rpos = document.querySelector("#1, #2");
    for (var i = 0; i &lt; rpos.length; i++) {
        rpos[i].setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;");
        document.body.appendChild(rpos[i]);
        var xy = getRandomPosition(rpos[i]);
        rpos[i].style.top = xy[0] + 'px';
        rpos[i].style.left = xy[1] + 'px';
    }
}```
````